# Center UILabel text on specific position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel with a long text and obliviously it can't be whole displayed.

So I was wondering if there's a method to center the displayed text with a custom offset.

For example, if my text is

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Now I get something like

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

But I want

> ...eiusmod tempor incidunt ut...

I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMakeRange to trim the string from certain location and to the location. If you would like to limit the characters to some length, then the following method trim the string with the length from exactly middle of the string.

```
- (NSString*)trimString:(NSString*)myLongString{
NSUInteger trimLength = 20;
NSUInteger stringLength = [string length];
if(stringLength < trimLength) return myLongString;
NSUInteger trimStartPosition = stringLength / 2 - trimLength / 2;
NSString *trimmedString = [myLongString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(trimStartPosition, trimLength) ];

return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"...%@...", trimmedString];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Insane-36 answer I've done this.

```
- (NSString *)trimString:(NSString *)string aroundWord:(NSString *)word withRadius:(NSUInteger)radius {

    NSString *prev = @"...", *next = @"...";
    NSUInteger centerStr = [string rangeOfString:word].location + word.length/2;
    NSUInteger start = centerStr - radius;

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, radius * 2);

    if (range.location + range.length > string.length) {

        range = NSMakeRange(string.length - range.length, range.length);
        next = @"";

    }

    if ((int)(range.location - range.length / 2) < 0) {

        range = NSMakeRange(0, range.length);
        prev = @"";
    }

    NSString *stringaRestituita = [string substringWithRange:range];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@", prev, stringaRestituita, next];

}
```

It works perfectly for me.

Comment: You might consider using ellipsis character … instead of three periods.